# Canvas.TextOut Seems to allow transparent trailing white space

Tags: delphi

I am in the process of relearning Delphi as have not programmed much of anything in years and have forgotten more than I ever learned! I have started with a simple file search routine and placing the found files in a multi-column listbox. The component I found was called MultiColListBox.pas off of Delphi3000.com. I have added a couple events to the sort routine and fixed an empty listbox error when enabling Sort.

When has two columns defined using this code and each is set for a length of 20, and in the first column your text (item) is say 100 characters long and the first item in the second column is say 20 characters long, you will see underneath the trailing whitespace text from the foirst column's text.

In the component, (Link to Code below), where the columns are drawn;

```
procedure TMultiColListBox.ListBoxDrawItem(Control : TWinControl;
                                       Index : Integer;
                                       Rect : TRect;
                                       State : TOwnerDrawState);
```

I have tried setting the brush to solid, and everything else I could think of. I finally realized that it is drawing the coordinates of the text with nothing trailing. Therefore we are getting a transparent effect which is not desired.

Usually I am overlooking something simple, so far, (can't see the forest for the trees). What might fix this issue? (This component has many items not working so lots of work but a great re-learning experience.

LINK To CODE: http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3360.asp
[MultiColListBox](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3360.asp)

Thanks!

JOhn

PS. I could not figure out how to format a cut and then pasted long code set or even the entire function to this forum, (short ones easy as above) so I provided the link to the compoenent code on Delphi3000.com.

Comment: The code in question is probably drawing text within a rectangle. The "transparent trailing area" is the bounds of the rectangle being drawn.   There is little substitute for a dual-monitor system, and debug single-stepping through your code, while it runs the stuff in the `Paint` method, to see how your control is rendered.   Since nobody here is using this delphi 3000 control, I really doubt you have an alternative to "fix it yourself". You have the source code so use it.  You said you want a learning experience; learn to single step through Paint methods and their children.

Comment: The linked code on Delphi3000 is really lame. Drop it.

Comment: I don't know what "drawing the coordinates of the text" or "a transparent effect" mean. Please post a picture. (Thanks for not posting a long block of code, but if you have to, formatting it is the same as formatting short blocks: paste the code, select it, and press the `{}` button above the edit window to insert four spaces in front of each line. Look at the preview below the edit box to ensure you got it right.)

Comment: @Rob. Thanks! I thought I tried the select and click the braces but it only seemed to work on the upper blocks and usually nothing after a 'begin' statement in the posted code. I know I will have ample opportunity to figure this site out in the coming months.

Comment: -1. Accepted answer does not help anyone else who will come here looking for help with the TextOut function.

Comment: @Rob I think that -1 is rather mean spirited. John is only trying to do the right thing. If you disagree say so but it really doesn't deserve a down vote in my view. If you want to downvote somebody I think you should be picking on me.

Comment: @David, the solution to John's problem is indeed to use the Windows common control. But the answer to the question he asked here is something else. My vote is to signal to others having trouble painting text, who might read the title thinking this would be a helpful question, that they're not going to find their answer here. With more details about the actual nature of the painting bug, we might be able to get an answer to this question, but I'd need to see a picture to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than fighting with this this 10 year old code you should simply switch to list view, [`TListView`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TListView) and set [`ViewStyle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TCustomListView.ViewStyle) to `vsReport`. This gives you a multi-column list using the native, modern-day Windows list control.

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I believe it solves your problem far better than the code you are trying to use.

Comment: Thanks David! I am aware... I am trying to relearn a lot of stuff and this was a good relearning challenge for me. I am stumped at the transparency so thought I'd ask...

Comment: or even more easier is to use a TDrawGrid (at least from my experiment)

Comment: I prefer the standard Windows list view, then.

Comment: I agree with David. A multi column listbox is merely a lame grid. Get a real grid, or if you want MS Common Controls, use the ListView with ViewStyle=vsReport. There are advantages to MS Common controls including screen-reader accessibility for disabled people, plus it renders as per Microsoft's desires for each OS it runs on.

Comment: I want to thank everyone for their answers but I am trying to relearn some of the stuff I thought I used to know. I was not wanting to use a listview as that works. Just trying to learn. But I will close this and accept David's answer and Thanks Rob Kennedy for his comments on how to post code.